# Change one column in two based on title of column and values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this type of DataFrame :

| general_key | secondary_key |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | 400 |
| 250 | 342 |

I need to change it

I tried to used df.T but it doesn't give me what I want.

Basically, I need it to change like this :

| keys_name | values |
| --- | --- |
| general_key | 1000 |
| general_key | 250 |
| secondary_key | 400 |
| secondary_key | 342 |

Comment: `out = df.melt(var_name="keys_name", value_name="values")`.